# Best way for implementation SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I'm an android java developer. I have a question, which of the ways to implement SurfaceView consumes less phone resources. My SurfaceView is redrawing every 7 milliseconds. I have used two ways to implement SurfaceView, with ValueAnimator and with Thread.  Both methods quickly redraw the SurfaceView, but I don't know which method consumes less phone resources.

Using ValueAnimator:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0,1);
animator.setDuration(2500);
    animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
    animator.addListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorListener(){
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator){}
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator){
                Log.d("ModMenu", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                if(!isOrdered){
                    if(order[0] < colors.length-1 && order[1] < colors.length-1){
                        order[0]+=1;
                        order[1]+=1;}
                    else{
                        isOrdered = true;
                        order[0]+=1;
                        order[1]-=1;}
                }
                else{
                    if(order[0] > 0 && order[1] > 0){
                        order[0]-=1;
                        order[1]-=1;}
                    else{
                        isOrdered = false;
                        order[0]-=1;
                        order[1]+=1;}
                }
                getRGBColors();
            }
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator){}
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator){}
        });
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
        Canvas canvas;
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator){
                body.setColor(evaluate(animator.getAnimatedFraction()));
                glow.setColor(evaluate(animator.getAnimatedFraction()));
                canvas = null;
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized(holder){
                    draw(canvas);
                    canvas.drawText(text, textX, textY, glow);
                    canvas.drawText(text, textX, textY, body);
                }
                if(canvas!=null){
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);}
            }
        });
```

Or using Thread:

```
previousTime = System.nanoTime()+staticTime;
    redrawTime = System.nanoTime();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            Canvas canvas;
            public void run(){
                while(isRunning){
                    if(System.nanoTime()-redrawTime>7000000){
                    if(previousTime<=System.nanoTime()){
                        int color = evaluate((double)((System.nanoTime()-previousTime))/animationTime);
                        body.setColor(color);
                        glow.setColor(color);
                        if(System.nanoTime()-previousTime>=animationTime){
                            if(!isOrdered){
                                if(order[0] < colors.length-1 && order[1] < colors.length-1){
                                    order[0]+=1;
                                    order[1]+=1;}
                                else{
                                    isOrdered = true;
                                    order[0]+=1;
                                    order[1]-=1;}
                            }
                            else{
                                if(order[0] > 0 && order[1] > 0){
                                    order[0]-=1;
                                    order[1]-=1;}
                                else{
                                    isOrdered = false;
                                    order[0]-=1;
                                    order[1]+=1;}
                            }
                            getRGBColors();
                            previousTime=System.nanoTime()+staticTime;}
                    }
                        canvas = null;
                        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                        synchronized(holder){
                            draw(canvas);
                            canvas.drawText(text, textX, textY, glow);
                            canvas.drawText(text, textX, textY, body);
                            redrawTime = System.nanoTime();
                        }
                        if(canvas!=null){
                            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);}
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    isRunning = true;
    thread.start();
```